# In QTP 12.51, how to identify dynamical element generated using ajax/jquery form

Tags: automated-testing, qtp, data-driven, vbscript

In my Datatable three rows are present. After clicking on Add button new row is generated and I need to put input values from datatable.

> **Problem:** How to identify field of each row dynamically for inserting values?

**Script:**

```
 Datatable.GetSheet(5)
    rowcount=Datatable.GetRowCount
    For i=1 to rowcount
         Datatable.SetCurrentRow(i)
         lenth =Datatable.Value(1,5)
         width= Datatable.Value(2,5)
         height= Datatable.Value(3,5)
         weight=Datatable.Value(4,5)
         piece=Datatable.Value(5,5)
Browser("Magma MCR").Page("Magma MCR").WebEdit("ship_info1[length_val]"Set lenth 
Browser("Magma MCR").Page("Magma MCR").WebEdit("ship_info1[width_val]").Set width 
Browser("Magma MCR").Page("Magma MCR").WebEdit("ship_info1[height_val]").Set height 
Browser("Magma MCR").Page("Magma MCR").WebEdit("ship_info1[weight_val]").Set weight 
Browser("Magma MCR").Page("Magma MCR").WebEdit("ship_info1[total_pieces]").Set piece
```

In this script,

Here in first row, web element name is `"ship_info1[height_val]`"

for next added row, web element gets chnaged to `"ship_info2[height_val]"`

So, I want to select this web-element dynamically. Please see the attached image.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding you want to dynamically fetch values for all the Ship info's , so in that case as you are keeping a loop for every row, you need to just put the code of updating values inside the loop and use **Regular expression** for Ship_info name, a wildcard for Ship_info.* for handling 1 ,2 etc values of different rows and also you can handle the same in loop by Ship_info.i .
There are multiple ways to handle this case.

Thanks!